# Error in Converting Array of Key/Value into Map

Tags: scala

Here is the code. I get error in **Step 4** when i try to convert each `Array` element in the `List`(which is the result of **Step 3**) into `Map`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
scala> // Step 1

scala> val inputList = List(  "data=first data || key1=r1v1 || key2=",
     |                        "data=second data || key1=r2v1 || key2=r2v2"
     |                       )
inputList: List[String] = List(data=first data || key1=r1v1 || key2=, data=second data || key1=r2v1 || key2=r2v2)

scala> // Step 2

scala> val splitted = inputList.map{ x =>
     |   x.split("\\|\\|")
     |    .map(_.trim)
     | }
splitted: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(data=first data, key1=r1v1, key2=), Array(data=second data, key1=r2v1, key2=r2v2))

scala> // Step 3

scala> val filteredList = splitted.map{ x =>
     |   val retval = for { element <- x
     |       val keyNval = element.split("=")
     |       if keyNval.size >= 2
     |     } yield {
     |       val splitted = element.split("=")
     |       val concatenated = splitted(0) + " -> " + splitted(1)
     |       concatenated
     |     }
     |   retval
     | }
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
filteredList: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(data -> first data, key1 -> r1v1), Array(data -> second data, key1 -> r2v1, key2 -> r2v2))

scala> // Step 4

scala> val dnryList = filteredList.map{ x =>
     |   x.toMap
     | }
<console>:32: error: Cannot prove that String <:< (T, U).
         x.toMap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toMap` requires elements of your collection to be tuples: `(T, U)`, while elements of your `filteredList` are `Array[String]`.

In "step3" you need to return tuples instead of strings, like this:

```
yield {
 val splitted = element.split("=")
 splitted(0) -> splitted(1)
}
```

`filteredList` is now `List[Array[(String, String)]]` and `toMap` works fine.